# javascript function of user control doesnt work for multiple instances of the control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-user-controls

I've made a user control for an ASP.NET page - the user control has a gridview and a global variable that keeps the last selected row.
in my main page I declare the user control twice. each user control has a different id.
finally, when I use both of the user controls, the code within the user control applies only on the first instance and not the second user control I declared on the page. how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you use a js library, like jQuery? If so you can use a wildcard selector.

Comment: Could you supply some sample code?

Comment: is there any other way? like adding some kind of id? I can't put the code here because it's very long.